# Lógica: Como funciona um aplicativo de localização de amigos?

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, mobile, lógica

estou estudando desenvolvimento mobile e me pintou uma dúvida: como funciona um app que localiza no mapa amigos em tempo real?

Exemplo: Um app que mostra no mapa onde estão seus amigos que tb tem o app, distancia em que eles estão e localização no mapa.

O app envia os dados de cada um para o servidor e este atualiza estes dados de tempos em tempos? Roda em background? Gostaria de entender esta lógica do funcionamento.

Abraços!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De maneira geral:

- O app coleta de tempos em tempos via [API de geolocalização](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) as coordenadas de todos os usuários, e envia o resultado para um servidor central. Implementações podem variar, porém em geral um [serviço é utilizado para a coleta](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html).
- Quando você acessa o app este faz uma requisição ao servidor - *envie-me as coordenadas atuais dos usuários A, B, C, ..., Z, assim como suas distâncias relativas à minha*.

Comment: Mas aí quando o usuário entra no app, e este solicita as coordenadas, o servidor pega a última localização armazenada dos amigos. Ele fica rodando em background nos dispositivos dos amigos (para enviar os dados nestes intervalos)?

Comment: @user3776181 Exatamente. De tempos em tempos o serviço instalado nos celulares dos amigos obtém um novo conjunto de coordenadas, e envia o resultado para o servidor central.

Comment: Exemplo de implementação: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Comment: Não tenho experiência com Android/Java, estou programando pelo Phonegap. Mas olhando o código que passou de exemplo, dá pra entender como o sistema funciona! =D

Muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @user3776181 Sempre um prazer ajudar!